# Release Phase in Lamport's Mutual Exclusion Algorithm

Tags: distributed-system, mutex

I was studying Lamport's mutual exclusion algorithm from the [original](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359563) paper, and noticed a difference in the release phase to the one given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_distributed_mutual_exclusion_algorithm). In the original paper, author states that :

> To release the resource, process Pi removes any Tm:Pi requests
>   resource message from its request queue and sends a (timestamped) Pi
>   releases resource message to every other process.

However in Wikipedia it is stated as follows :

> Upon exiting the critical section, remove its request from the queue
>   and send a release message to every process.

As you notice the original paper mentions **any Tm:Pi requests resource message from its request queue** which is slighly confusing to me. According to my understanding the process Pi upon exiting the critical section removes its request from the queue, but the paper doesn't make an explicit mention about that.